# UML use case diagram (extends)

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

Discussing about the extends used in use case diagram, i am wondering that if edit and delete order can extends to view order. Because when the customer view the order he/she can choose to edit or delete it or not to do anything with it

Answer (score 1):

All CRUD use cases are borderline (from my POV). You can go and `<<extend>>` the `view` (aka Read) use case with the remaining CUD pendants. However, what I often do in such cases is to place a `Manage X` use case and stereotype it with `<<CRUD>>`. Especially if you have a couple of `X` to be handled.